# Put dots and style the chart

Tags: css, highcharts

I would like to place orange dots like such on a highcharts:

http://www.dev2one.com/econometering/highcharts/graph-conso.jpg

Any suggestion how to make them ? and style them too

Thanks alot

Regards

Comment: What chart type is that ?

Comment: you can find the api here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts for the 'dots' you want `plotOptions.line.marker` and then you should be able to use `lineWidth: Number` to remove the lines

Comment: Hi wf4, thanks for your answer, I tried out the plotOptions.line.marker, it works pretty well, what I want now is remove the lines between the dots, and lineWidth remove the lines around the dots not between the dots...http://jsfiddle.net/dqepok9d/

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look is the Highcharts API which you can find here:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

To remove the lines and format the marker, you need to look at the `plotOption.line`. In your fiddle, you have added the `lineWidth: 0,` to the `marker` but you should have added it to the `series` like this:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#F27D00',
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqepok9d/1/